# Listview with key field

Tags: android

I want to display a listview when clicked be able to get the items key value.  How would I go about that.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: you need to elaborate more on what exactly your question is. show some code, show what you've done, details details!!

Answer (score 5):

The way you would go about doing what you're talking about is to use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) with a simple class for creating the objects you'd like to use.

For instance, if you'd like to make a listview of People including their name and their age, and want to display just their names in a listview, you would first create a Person class as follows:

```
public class Person {
  int age;
  String name;

  public Person(int age, String name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.name; //what you want displayed for each row in the listview
  }

}
```

Then, in your java file that's utilizing the listview (say it's called PersonTracker.java), you would call:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Person>(PersonTracker.this, R.layout.list_people, people);
lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View currView, int position, long id) {
    Person selected = (Person)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String selectedName = selected.name;  //ideally this would probably be done with accessors
    int selectedHeight = selected.height;

    //Do whatever you need to with the name and height here
    //such as passing via intents to the next activity...

  }
});
```

where list_people is just a generic xml layout with just a textview that controls how each row looks, and people is the xml layout that contains the listview.

As you can see above, in your onItemClick function you can get whatever you want from the Person associated with the list item that's clicked on.

Anyway, hope that helps someone out and saves the time I spent figuring it out...i need some sleep...

Answer (score 0):

The items key value of a listview ? Are you looking for [onListItemClick from ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)) ?

Comment: No, I am looking to store a record id with every row, but display text.  How are the keys stored, and related to the row items and yet not displayed?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: I want to read a database and store a record_id of let's say 9104 and the displayed item in the list is "Blue Donkeys", when I click on "Blue Donkeys" I want to get the key "9104".

Any ideas?

thanks,
Dean